# Show data from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have table part like this

```
id_part process 
1         1
2         2
3         3
```

Each process have table in database

```
proces 1
id_prs1 name     qty  id_part
1       blank     2     1
2       piercing  5     2
3       bending   6     3

proces 2
id_prs2 name   qty  id_part
1       stamp  2       2
2       pierc  4       3

proces 3
id_prs2 name   qty  id_part
1       cut     2       3
```

i want show in form based on value process in table part, if they have 2 process then they show table process 1 and process 2 and if the number 3 they will show table process 1,2 and 3.

i already try this

```
SELECT part.process, process1.name, process1.qty,process2.name, process2.qty, process3.name, process3.qty FROM part inner JOIN process 1 on process1.id_part = part.id_part inner JOIN process 2 on process2.id_part = part.id_part inner JOIN process 3 on process3.id_part = part.id_part where part.id_part = '$part'
```

but in form only show if the process in table part have value 3.

process value = 2
[image]

process value = 3
[image]

Comment: use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Your query contains errors. Sometimes a table is called `process 1`, an invalid name, and other times it is called `process1`. This tells me that what you state can't true. This query should always fail.